# How to update 2D Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var memberName = input.question("Please enter member's name: ");
        memberName = memberName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + memberName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        subMemberGroups();
        if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)) {
            const memberGroupIndex = memberGroup.findIndex((e) => e.name === memberName)
            if (memberGroupIndex !== -1) {
                memberGroup.splice(memberGroupIndex, 1); // if exists remove it
                console.log("Member deleted!\n");
            } else {
                console.log("Member does not exist.\n");
            }
        } 
        else {
            console.log("Member does not exist.\n");
        }
        choices();
```

```
while (true) {
            var memberName = input.question("Please enter member's name: ");
            memberName = memberName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + memberName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
            subMemberGroups();
            if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)) {
                console.log ("\nMember's name exists in database. Please enter a new name.");
            }
            else {
                var memberDOB = input.question("Please enter member's date of birth: ");
                var memberDJ = input.question("Please enter member's date joined: ");
                var userNew = new Member (memberName, 'Ruby', memberDJ, memberDOB, 0);
                memberGroup.push(userNew);
                break;
            }
        }
```

```
while (true) {
        var memberName = input.question("Please enter member's name: ");
        memberName = memberName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + memberName.substring(1).toLowerCase();
        subMemberGroups();
        if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)) {
            console.log ("\nMember's name exists in database. Please enter a new name.");
        }
```

```
function subMemberGroups() {
    for (var i = 0; i < memberGroup.length; i++) {
        subMemberGroup.push(memberGroup[i]["name"]);
    }
}
```

```
memberGroup = [userJohn, userLemuel];
subMemberGroup = ['John', 'Samuel'];
var userJohn = ['John', '20'];
var userLemuel = ['Lemuel', '22'];
var userJohn = new Member ['John', '24'];
```

The first block of code will delete the details of either of them depending on what the user input. The code works fine. However, after trying to add new member, it prompts me that the member already exist. How do I permanently delete the user details in the 2D array?

The second block of code will add new member. However, after the first block of code executes, the second block of code says that the name already existing although I have already ran the first block od code to delete the member i.e John.

I was wondering what can I do to resolve this?

Comment: `.question()` is not a built-in method. `subMemberGroups()` isn't defined. `Member` is an undefined class. Also, `userJohn` and `userLemuel` looks like syntactically incorrect arrays. So, if we have no clue what those do...what kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: also, `var userJohn = ('John', '20');` is not valid javascript, is the meant to be an array or a function call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you remove a member, you remove him from `memberGroup` but he is still in `subMemberGroup`, when you try to add / remove a member, you first check inside `subMemberGroup` if he is already existing

Try edit like this :

```
if (subMemberGroup.includes(memberName)) {
    const memberGroupIndex = memberGroup.findIndex((e) => e.name === memberName)
    if (memberGroupIndex !== -1) {
        memberGroup.splice(memberGroupIndex, 1); // if exists remove it
        subMemberGroup.splice(subMemberGroup.indexOf(memberName), 1); // add this line to remove member from subMemberGroup

        console.log("Member deleted!\n");
    } else {
        console.log("Member does not exist.\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, your solution works. However, that only works when user enter a new member, deletes it then add again.

Comment: Hi, your solution works. However, it only works for once or twice, after which it goes back to the same error that I have previously said

Comment: What do you mean ? When you add more than 2 user it doesn't works any more ? Or when you remove / add again more than twice (the same user) it doesn't works any more ?

Comment: Sorry, let me specify. When you run the code above twice or more, it does not work as intended anymore

Comment: Which error happens ? Can you please give an exemple by editing your post ?

Comment: After running your suggested code twice or more, when I try to add a new member it just prompts me that the user is already in the database even though I have deleted it.

Comment: Can you `console.log` the content of `subMemberGroup` && `memberGroup` we'll try to debug it

Comment: I have edited the post above, lets just say that userJohn is my main array, and userJohn and userLemuel is just what I am adding after running the code.

Comment: okay I managed to solve it myself

Comment: Hi, I need help again, I have updated the post above

Comment: The third block of code is when I try to add member again after deleting it. However it kept on saying that the name is already in the database

Comment: the subMemberGroups pushes all the name inside a seperate array

Comment: I think `subMemberGroups` should take parameter

Comment: What do you mean by that?